# Почему не работает код?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Почему не работает код? Проблема в цикле

```
 function welcomeAnimate(){
    var enter = document.getElementById("enter")
    var login =  document.getElementById("login")
    var password =  document.getElementById("password")
    var box = [login, password]
    enter.onclick = function (){
        for(var i = 0; i > 2; ++i){
            box[i].style.display = "block";
         }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Ты прежде чем вопросы то задавать, лучше бы смотрел код.
чисто если логически рассуждать если i равна нулю, то цикл будет выполнятся пока твой ноль будет больше 2-х?

Comment: @Rimon А ты прежде чем дизморалить человека, подумай что это убивает стремление к развитию, да вопрос был задан из-за невнимательности, но сообщество stack создано помогать по всем вопросам it.

Comment: @Zow Не забывай для логического завершения строки ставить подобные символы ; (а то отвыкнешь)
Читабельность повышают :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for(var i = 0; i < 2; ++i){
    box[i].style.display = "block";
 }
```

может так?